# Java scan.nextLine() only waits for user input of int user input; doesn't wait for string user input

Tags: java, user-input, println

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java, programm not stopping for scan.nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268598/java-programm-not-stopping-for-scan-nextline)

```
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Tuition Calculator Program.");
    System.out.println("How many total credits are you taking?");
    credits = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Are you a Washington resident? y/n");
    resident = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Are you a graduate student? y/n");
    grad = scan.nextLine();
```

I'm new to Java and relatively new to programming. On a PC working in jGRASP. In the code above, I simply need the user to enter number of credits (the int response), residency (a string), and graduate status (string).

It allows the user to enter credits, but then prints the resident question and the graduate question together. It doesn't stop and allow the user to enter an answer to the residency question. (It does allow me to enter my response to the graduate question.)

Other related questions here on the forum haven't helped; I have tried adding in an extra line to swallow any extra line breaks, but that hasn't done it. Perhaps I added the wrong type of line. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268598/1519533) was helpful, but didn't provide a solution that worked.

Comment: The answer in your linked thread is exactly right.  Use `nextLine` everywhere and `Integer.parseInt` to convert to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is that happening?**
If you try to print `resident` you will find that it prints the `newline` character.
Actually what is happening here is this. The enter pressed by you after the input of `credits` is being taken as string ans is copied to `resident` variable. So what you need here is avoid that newline character.
**Solution**
read the `credits` using `nextLine()` and parse it to integer using `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
 System.out.println("Welcome to the Tuition Calculator Program.");  
    System.out.println("How many total credits are you taking?");  
    credits = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());  
    System.out.println("Are you a Washington resident? y/n");
    resident = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Are you a graduate student? y/n");
    grad = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks cdev, that's a great explanation. Answers to similar questions here seem to indicate this will always happen when switching from int user input to string user input. I'll watch for that.