# Java finding the minimum value from Scanner input always resulting in zero

Tags: java, if-statement, input, minimum

This is my first Java program. It is supposed to allow a user to enter int grades between 0 and 100. If the user enters a negative value, data entry ceases and statistics are displayed. I cannot incorporate static methods, math, or arrays.

I am having an issue with finding the minimum grade, minGrade. Regardless of what values are entered when the program is running, minGrade always results in zero. I have been tinkering with this for a while now to no avail.

The other issue I am having is that when I run the program, and I enter a bunch of int, but then enter some alphabet letters to test the error-checking, the program parses the user twice, instead of once.

```
"Please enter a numeric grade between 0 and 100, inclusive, and press Enter:"
```

The respective code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Grades {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the Course Code and and press Enter:");
        String courseCode = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + courseCode + "\n");

        int grade = 0;

        int numberOfGrades = 0;
        int maxGrade = 0;
        int minGrade =0;
        double avgGrade = 0;
        int sumGrades = 0;

        int sentinel = 0;



        do

        {


                **System.out.println("Please enter a numeric grade between 0 and 100, inclusive, and press Enter:");**
                while(!keyboard.hasNextInt())
                {

                    System.out.println("Please enter a numeric grade between 0 and 100, inclusive, and press Enter:");
                    keyboard.nextLine();

                }

                grade = keyboard.nextInt();
                if((grade <=100) && (grade >= 0))
                {
                    numberOfGrades++;
                    sumGrades += grade;
                    sentinel = 0;

                    if(maxGrade < grade)
                        maxGrade = grade;

                    **if(minGrade > grade)
                        minGrade= grade;**
                }
                else if(grade > 100)
                {

                    System.out.println("The entered number was greater than 100. Please enter a number between 0 and 100 inclusive, "
                            + "or input a negative number to exit Grade entry");
                    sentinel = 0;
                }
                else if(grade <0)
                {
                    grade = 0;//maybe?
                    sentinel = -1;

                }

        }
        while((grade >100) || (sentinel == 0));


        avgGrade = (sumGrades/numberOfGrades);



        System.out.println("You entered: " + "\ngrade: " + grade + "\n" + "sentinel: "+ sentinel +
                "\nSum of Grades: " + sumGrades +"\nNumber of Grades: "+ numberOfGrades +"\nAverage Grades: " + avgGrade
                + "\nMaxium Grade: "+ maxGrade+"\nMinimum Grade: "+minGrade);
    }

}
```

Any input on this, the form of my code for my first java program, or anything else would be greatly appreciated.

The last issue I am having is that the average grade always has a tenth place of zero. How can I get the tenth place to not be zero and the actual average amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `minGrade` is that you initialize it to 0. This is already the min value, hence no other values will be less than this. (You in fact ensure this even more so by setting negative grades to 0.) Initialize it to the max value (100).

It looks like your "double prompt" issue is a [common one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268598/java-programm-not-stopping-for-scan-nextline) with `nextLine` and `nextInt`. The solution seems to be using only `nextLine` and then parsing the return value of that for an `Integer` object. (And printing out your "invalid input" text on a `NumberFormatException`.

Finally, your `avgGrade` is always `xx.0` as you are dividing two integers, which always gives an integer back. You need to cast one to a double to get a double back:

```
avgGrade = ((double)sumGrades/numberOfGrades);
```

Comment: Yes, I mean it asks the user twice. ' .nextLine()' and 'nextInt() , how would I go about making sure that it does not ask twice when the number is not an 'Int' . I myself do not understand those two statements completely and java documentation hasn't helped much.

Thanks, the double conversion worked. I tried avgGrade = 1.0d * (x/y), it didn't seem to work

Comment: @SajSeesSound you need to cast one of the items to a double like I have shown in my code example. The problem is (x/y) will truncate to an int, so you need to do ((double)x/y). I am working on the double prompt issue.

Comment: Lastly, Does the value of 'grade' not change before the first 'if' statement to something other than zero? If so, why does the value for the calculations iterate as zero?

Comment: @SajSeesSound I found a solution to your double prompt issue. I'm not sure what you're asking for `grade`. It should get a value from `nextInt`, the value you enter.

Comment: This results in the prompt requiring two user inputs instead of what it was originally doing, displaying two prompts but requiring one input.

Comment: @SajSeesSound I found a post with a similar issue. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`minGrade` will never be set to anything other than 0 because 0 will never be greater than the grade entered, so this check fails `if(minGrade > grade)`. Try initializing `minGrade` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.