# How to read in lines separately in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a Nim game in Java, and part of my code is to read in two names if the game is to have two human players, but when I run the code it prints the statement asking for the first name and the statement asking for the second name, which only allows me to enter a name for the second player. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

```
System.out.println("Please enter a name for Player 1: ");
String player1Name = scan.nextLine();
player1.setName(player1Name);
System.out.println("Please enter a name for Player 2: ");
String player2Name = scan.nextLine();
player2.setName(player2Name);
```

Comment: please show us some previous code, such as when you import and set up your scanner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java, programm not stopping for scan.nextLine()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268598/java-programm-not-stopping-for-scan-nextline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`String player1Name = scan.next();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a name for Player 1: ");
String player1Name = scan.nextLine();
player1.setName(player1Name);
System.out.println("Please enter a name for Player 2: ");
String player2Name = scan.nextLine();
player2.setName(player2Name);
```